# Nhibernate BuildSessionFactory Null Exception

Tags: nhibernate, nullreferenceexception, sessionfactory

I'm getting BuildSessionFactory null exception.

Using Nhibernate 3.3.3.4000 , .NET 4.5 , MVC 4 and;

```
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
```

When i try this code block im getting null exception. Tried install nuget package several times and checked web.config. Nothing changed.

Anyone can help me?

**edit-1 StackTrace of Exception**

```
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  

 at NHibernate.Engine.NamedSQLQueryDefinition..ctor(String query, INativeSQLQueryReturn[] queryReturns, IList`1 querySpaces, Boolean cacheable, String cacheRegion, Int32 timeout, Int32 fetchSize, FlushMode flushMode, Nullable`1 cacheMode, Boolean readOnly, String comment, IDictionary`2 parameterTypes, Boolean callable)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.NamedSQLQueryBinder.<>c__DisplayClass1.<AddSqlQuery>b__0(IDictionary`2 param0)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
```

Thanks already.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: Can you post the answer as an answer and mark it correct please?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution! In my model mapping I left blank one of my SQL-queries. :)